# Get records with array values in a field using eloquent

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have this table that has a field I called `videos` and the type of that field is `array`. Now I want to get all the records that have at least 1 value inside `videos field`. Below is my code that doesn't return what I want.

```
$prod = Product::where(array('videos' => array('$ne' => 0)))->get();
```

I am using laravel 4.2 and mongoDb as my database.

Comment: Fetch all those record that have at least  `1` video link or whatever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am glad that I found the solution to this. It needs to know that field `videos` exists and not empty. Take a look at below code:

```
$prod = Product::where(array('videos' => array('$ne' => [], '$exists' => true)))->get();
```

Comment: @basheer thanks for giving me a hint that I could also use `[ ]`to represent an array from your previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

May be this answer could help you as I came up with the solution that `Json` encodes the data in array. So when it's empty the value will be `[]`. So you can query it something like this

```
$prod = Product::where('videos', '!=', '[]')->get();
```

Comment: I tried your code above, but it is still returning videos array that are empty. Thank you. I hope you can come up with more answers